# Trying to install openerp7 on Mac OS X Mavericks?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

image not found

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.5.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.5.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I was trying first with an environ, bad the same error. Please help!

```
Mavericks 10.9.4
postgresql-9.3.4-4-osx
python2.7
psycopg-2.5.3
```

Comment: reading the error, it looks like it can't find the SSL version 1.0.0 library.

Comment: Reading your answer I just take a look to the syslim that I created in /usr/lib and yes, they have another link. Changed and it go. Thanks for everything, it was very helpfully.